# How to fix no such module 'CSVImporter' xcode error when installing CSVImporter

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

After installing CSVImporter I still can't use it. When I import it at the beginning of some file with `import CSVImporter`, it says `No such module 'CSVImporter'` What could be wrong?

Xcode 9.0.1

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'worDecks' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'CSVImporter', '~> 1.7'
end
```

**edit**
Sorry, had to delete it to figure out what the problem was.
Even if I just install the package and build the project, it throws a lot of errors.

The package is listed in the list of frameworks

Comment: Did you opened the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj? Do you see the CSVImporter in your project in the navigator?

Comment: @Larme, Sorry I almost have no experience with xcode. Here's what I have when I click on + at "Embedded binaries" https://i.imgur.com/S5f72eP.png But if I select CSVImporter from there, the build still fails(https://i.imgur.com/3acxnzC.png)